# Size of created pdf file

Tags: vba, excel

When creating a .pdf file using the code pasted below the size of the file gets to around 375 KB, but when creating a pdf using the built in pdf creator from the print menu in excel, the file only gets about 40 KB

```
Worksheets("Journal").Activate
Range("JournalArea").Select

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
'.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
.Zoom = 50
.BlackAndWhite = True
End With

With Selection
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    filePath & title & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:= _
    True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

So the question is, am I including unnecessary data in the pdf file, and if so how do i exclude that?

Any suggestions will be much appriciated.

Comment: What happens when you replace `xlQualityStandard` by `xlQualityMinimum`

Comment: try one more thing `IncludeDocProperties=False`

Comment: hold on where is *`the built in pdf creator from the print menu in excel`*?

Comment: @vba4all: I guess he means the `.SaveAs PDF`

Comment: That reduces the file size to about 280 K, so it's in the right direction.

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's not under the Print menu? just asking for clarification :)

Comment: I'm wasn't sure what to call it, but what I mean is where you selct printer, you can also select create Pdf. @vba4all

Comment: Ah! Which pdf creator are you using `Primopdf`? `Acrobat`? This would definitely give you a different size. Excel uses builtin method when using `.ExportAsFixedFormat`

Comment: @SiddharthRout It's PdfCreator 1.6.2 and since i'm on a company computer that's about all the imformation I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pdf creating software are software which specialize in creating pdfs. And hence probably they use efficient way of creating a pdf. On the other hand Excel is not specifically meant for `Pdf Creation`. There will always be a difference in the way the pdf is created in both the applications and hence there will be a difference in size.

The most you can do ins Excel is compromise on pdf quality and do not include certain information in the pdf. For example

1. Specifying the quality by changing `xlQualityStandard` to `xlQualityMinimum` in `Quality:=`
2. By not including the `Document Properties`

As I mentioned in the comment above, this is IMHO all that you can do when using `.ExportAsFixedFormat`

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                     Filename:= filePath & title & ".pdf", _
                     Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
                     IncludeDocProperties:= False, _
                     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                     OpenAfterPublish:=False
```